# Typo3: completely broken, blank page :(

Tags: typo3

I have created an extension in `typo3conf/ext` according to this [Tutorial](https://advitum.de/2013/05/einstieg-in-extbase-ein-plugin-ohne-models/#comment-190084)

After finishing the coding I logged into the back-end and clicked on install/activate.

First message was `"oops. error"`. No details, just that. Then later I found out that he cannot find `Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension`.

Which is weird because according to the tutorial it's fine to use it? The error page was always showing, I was unable to get back into the back-end or even show the normal non-back-end page.

So I moved the folder of my extension out of `typo3conf/ext` in order to get back into the `back-end / normal mode`. But now all I see is a blank page. ***Why?***

Comment: Add namespace `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::class` instead of deprecated syntax `Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension`. This syntext no longger support with TYPO3 7.x or later version of TYPO3.

Comment: okay that worked, thanks. how can I find out what was deprecated when? it seems to be a mess, all those google search results and all those different versions .. (EDIT: the problem is, I have to work with an old version, there's really no way around it)

Answer (score 0):

You see a blank page, because the error messages are not shown. And there are errors, because you most likely didn't clear caches, and because you didn't uninstall the extension (but just removed it instead, if I understand your post correctly).

You need to:
 - clear the typo3temp folder (delete everything that is there)
 - remove the plugin from "PackageStates.php", also "LocalConfiguration.php" (there the ext saves some settings; if you haven't any settings, you won't find your ext there) 
 - and maybe even truncate (that is: delete all data, but NOT the table itself!) from all "cache_*" and "cf_cache_*" tables in your DB

If you know, how to do it, enable "Development_Mode". There are more ways to do that, but best start here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Bootstrapping/Index.html
And search Google for "TYPO3 SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development" 
That way you won't get white pages, but verbose error messages. (Of course you need to unset those settings again, when you go live.)

Please post back about your success. And if so, please post TYPO3 version, php version, operating system and what kind of local dev you use (MAMP, WAMP...)

The tutorial is very old, TYPO3 changed a bit in the meantime. Better search for a newer one.

Comment: It is easy to find outdated tutorials for TYPO3, there are just too many. Also, the current re-organisation of the TYPO3 documentation leads to a loss of many links that were previously active, but now result in a 404, when a topic is found on Google. Currently this is pretty annoying, but one day, when the documentation has found its finally structure, this will most definitely be great resource! So always check ad dig through the documentation! (And follow the team on slack to stay informed.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a very old tutorial used on a new version of TYPO3 (specify your version!).
The linked tutorial is for TYPO3 6.0, a version out of support for years.
Since then a lot has changed. especially you need to use namespaces (instead of class names like `Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension`)

Aside from removing your extension sources from `typo3conf/ext/<extkey>/` you need to remove all copies which have been made.
The best way would be to use the install tool (`/typo3/install/`) and clear all caches.
If the install tool has the same error try to remove `typo3temp/Cache/` and remove the entry for your extension from `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`.

Answer (score 0):

To check the depreciation in TYPO3 you can check the official documentation site here.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/

You can add the TYPO3 extension compatibility extension.

**TER**

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/compatibility6/
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/compatibility7/

**GIT**

https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/compatibility6
https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/compatibility7

Here is a nice blog for extension level depreciation:

http://www.typo3tiger.de/blog/post/upgrading-pibase-extensions-auf-62-lts-oder-76-lts.html

Hope this will help you!

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Yes I do know that this is not a proper answer to the occurred problem. Thanks.

TBH: The tutorial you mentioned is WAY outdated, not to mention it's for 6.0 (which wasn't even a LTS version). It's from late 2013. TYPO3 changed a lot since then. TYPO3 v 6 was build for php 5.3+. TYPO3 8.7 requires at least php 7.0. Means only this caused a lot of changes.

With that said (useless complaining mode "off"):

You may want to have a look into the official documentation. It also contains basic tutorials of creating your very own first extension.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/Index.html

Also an very good example is the Bootstrap & introduction package.

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/introduction/
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package/

And for TYPO3 Backend form stuff, the styleguide is a very good piece of example:

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/styleguide/

Greetings,
KamiYang